# jupyter notebook (dyld: Library not loaded)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, dyld

Pardon me for my stupidity. I tried to run `jupyter notebook` on Mac terminal after:

- upgrading python from 3.6 to 3.9
- deleting files in `/usr/local/Cellar/`

then I got the following error

> `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python`
> `Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6`
> `Reason: imagenot found`
> `Abort trap: 6`

What I am trying to do is just to upgrade python and packages used by Jupyter Notebook. Could someone help advise what went wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew upgrade python3
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the following error `shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory ... Error: The current working directory doesn't exist, cannot proceed.`

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171785/how-to-repair-and-or-reinstall-homebrew-safely